# Haskell error algebraic types

Tags: haskell

I am learning how to create algebraic types in Haskell.

I just started and want that two arguments are solved mathematically.

Here is my code:

```
data calculate = firstargument Int | sndargument Int 
doit :: calculate-> Int
doit (calculate firstargument sndargument) = firstargument + sndargument
```

I get an error " Not a data constructor firsrargument "

What is wrong ?

---

**EDITED NEW CODE**:

Here is my changed code:

```
data Calculate = Firstargument Int   | Sndargument Int 

f :: Calculate
f = Firstargument 1

s:: Calculate 
s = Sndargument 2

addCalc ::  Calculate -> Calculate -> Int
addCalc (Firstargument x) (Firstargument y) = x+y 
-- not the complete pattern matching , but should be enough for testing purposes.
```

Comment: May I suggest reading "Learn You A Haskell"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type constructors and data constructors must start with a capital letter in Haskell.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, data types and constructors must start with a capital letter

```
data Calculate = FirstArgument Int | SndArgument Int
```

Now you can construct values of type `Calculate` as

```
f :: Calculate
f = FirstArgument 1

s :: Calculate
s = SndArgument 2
```

Second, you can't add them together directly without making it an instance of the `Num` typeclass, but it'd be easier right now to just use pattern matching (unless you need other arithmetic operators):

```
addCalc :: Calculate -> Calculate -> Int
addCalc (FirstArgument x) (FirstArgument y) = x + y
addCalc (FirstArgument x) (SndArgument y) = x + y
addCalc (SndArgument x) (FirstArgument y) = x + y
addCalc (SndArgument x) (SndArgument y) = x + y
```

However, judging by your example, it appears that you are misunderstanding how to use algebraic data types.  I'd suggest brushing up on them by reading [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) and [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/)

---

**EDIT**

To use this in GHCi, you could do

```
> addCalc (FirstArgument 1) (FirstArgument 2)
3
> let x = FirstArgument 20
> :type x
Calculate
> let y = SecondArgument 40
> :type y
Calculate
> addCalc x y
60
```

Comment: Hello, 
thank you for your respones

Here is my changed code :

    entdata Calculate = Firstargument Int   | Sndargument Int 
    
    f :: Calculate
    f = Firstargument 1

    s:: Calculate 
    s = Sndargument 2

    addCalc ::  Calculate -> Calculate -> Int
    addCalc (Firstargument x) (Firstargument y) = x+y 
    -- not the complete pattern matching , but should be enough for testing purposes.

It refuses to compile when i type "addCalc (5) (3)"
It says " no instance for Num " 
So , exactly that , what you just mentioned.

How can I fix the problem ?

Comment: You have to wrap the `5` and `3` each in a constructor to make it have type `Calculate`.  The value `5` by itself has the type `Num a => a`, which is not the same type.

Comment: Also, if you have new code, please edit your question, it's much harder to read large chunks of code in a comment

Comment: What do you mean by wrapping ? Can you give an example how to type it in GHCI ?

Comment: A question more to be ensure of this :
Why can't I just use (deriving Num ) ?

Comment: @user2938633 Because `Num` is not a derivable class.  Your `addCalc` function returns an `Int`, not another `Calculate`, but even if it did, how would the compiler know which constructor (`FirstArgument` or `SndArgument`) to wrap the result in?  What if you always want to multiply the contents of a `SndArgument` by 2?  It can't know that, you have to define it yourself.  You can actually derive `Num`, but only in a special circumstance and with a compiler extension, it's not what you need here, I promise.